# In Mongoose how do I create a MongooseArray/Collection in a model that has .create(), .id(), and .remove() functionality

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

My Schemas:

```
Account: mongoose.model('Account', new Schema({
    account_name: String,
    company: String,
    notes: String,
    contact_info: [this.ContactInfo]
})),
ContactInfo: mongoose.model('ContactInfo', new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    notes: String 
}))
```

When I try to do any actions on contact_info though, it says that the methods don't exist.

```
var c = new ContactInfo...);
var a = new Account(...);

a.contact_info.create(c); //error, create doesn't exsit
a.contact_info.push(c); //works
a.contact_info.id(...).remove(); //id doesn't exist
```

Am I doing something wrong?

My full code is here (not too much of it): https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/master/accounts.js

I'm receiving input from Backbone.js by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be within [`schemas.js`](https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/4fbbcb24c94e08e75423b638b42ececcff014c9d/schemas.js). When defining an object by literal, `this` won't refer to the object being defined:

```
// ...
    contact_info: [this.ContactInfo]
// ...
```

It'll instead refer to the context surrounding the literal -- in the case of Node modules, the [`exports` object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) -- which doesn't have a `ContactInfo` property. So, the result is:

```
// ...
    contact_info: [undefined]
// ...
```

You'll still have an `Array`, which is why `push` is available. But, Mongoose doesn't know to make it a [`MongooseDocumentArray`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-documentarray-js), so it won't have the `id`, `create`, etc. methods.

You'll have to define your models outside the object to have a reference to them. Also note the change in order:

```
var ContactInfo = mongoose.model('ContactInfo', new Schema({
    // ...
});

var Account = mongoose.model('Account', new Schema({
    // ...
    contact_info: [ContactInfo]
});

module.exports = {
    Account: Account,
    ContactInfo: ContactInfo
};
```

Or, attach them to `exports` so `this.ContactInfo` is set (same order):

```
exports.ContactInfo = ...;
exports.Account = ...;
```

Comment: Tried that (pushed in repo). Unfortunately I am still getting the same error

Comment: @AnatoliyZaslavskiy The reference may need to be to the `Schema` rather than the `Model`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html. Try `contact_info: [ContactInfo.schema]` ([ref](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-schema)) instead.

Comment: Now I am having a really strange issue. .create() works (no errors). In fact it even spits back an ID for the contact I just created. However, when I look in my database, nothing is there (empty array), and when I do a.contact_info.id(ID) it returns null. What do you think is happening to the contact info I just created? (Updated source in repo) https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/master/accounts.js#L108

Comment: @AnatoliyZaslavskiy The [`create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray-create) method doesn't appear to alter the array is was called on (see the "show code"). It just creates the instance, similar to `new ContactInfo(...)` for sub-doc types. So, follow the `create` with `a.contact_info.push(c);`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! That did the trick! I wonder why .create doesn't do the .push() for you (like in Backbone). Seems pretty intuitive...

Comment: `push()` already casts the argument and adds it to the array. `create()` is useful when you need a reference to the subdoc and makes no assumption about whether you actually want to add it to the array.

Comment: @aaronheckmann: what actually happens when you create() a document? where does it live on the server? I've tried looking around in Mongo browser and it was nowhere to be found.

Comment: @AnatoliyZaslavskiy It's only in memory after a `.create()`, same as after `new ContactInfo(...)`. You still have to `.save()` it either directly or as part of a sub-doc collection to find it in Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I did a few things wrong:

In Schemas, reference other Schemas NOT Models:

Good:

```
var ContactInfoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    account_name: String,
    contact_info: [ContactInfoSchema] 
});

var ContactInfo = mongoose.model('ContactInfo', ContactInfoSchema);

var Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

Bad:
    var ContactInfoSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        email: String,
        phone: String,
        notes: String 
    });

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    account_name: String,
    contact_info: [ContactInfo] //subtle difference
});

var ContactInfo = mongoose.model('ContactInfo', ContactInfoSchema);

var Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

The other thing is doing the following doesn't save anything!!!

```
account.contact_info.create(params);
account.save();
```

You also have to do

```
var c = account.contact_info.create(params);
account.contact_info.push(c);
account.save();
```

For those interested here are the CRUD methods I created for Account and ContactInfo.

https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/f94fcd4b05bf0af4f34a0e00f4ff79ebf64e24e1/accounts.js